KDB q: how to convert a table into a string?
I need to compute md5 of a table in KDB. However, md5 can only (as far as I know) be called on a string. So, how can one convert a table in KDB to a single string representation? It does not matter if the result is human-readable as long as it is deterministic.
tab:flip `items`sales`prices!(`nut`bolt`cam`cog;6 8 0 3;10 20 15 20)
md5 tab / does not work
md5 string tab / does not work

Thank you very much for your help!

Where is the kdb table coming from, on disk? If it's a flat table on disk you could use the OS implementation of md5 on the on-disk object. Would avoid the need to (re)serialise and stringify within kdb. E.g. on linux it would be system"md5sum /path/to/object"

This feels like an xy problem (https://xyproblem.info/). What are you hoping to achieve by calculating the md5sum of a kdb table? As already suggested, hashing the on-disk data is going to be a much more performant approach.

The data resides in a temporary table on a remote KDB process and is transferred to a local processes in chunks. In case of an error during transfer, I calculate md5 sum to check that the data has not changed: if it has changed, the download process is restarted from the beginning, if it has not, then the download continues where the previous download left off.

String based outputs truncate based on console size so are not reliable in comparing the whole table.
Using -8! to serialize the table to bytes then you can convert to characters to run md5:
https://code.kx.com/q/kb/serialization/
q)md5 `char$-8!([] a:1 2 3 )
0xeb5cc58551051573c696ea6f746c0dc8

One item to watch out for still is attributes on data:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/set-attribute/
q)md5 `char$-8!([] a:1 2 3 )
0xeb5cc58551051573c696ea6f746c0dc8
q)md5 `char$-8!([] a:`g#1 2 3 )
0xda110d1ca3127bffe0a76ea21574f91d

You can remove at a column level:
q)md5 `char$-8!{c:cols x;![x;();0b;c!{(#;enlist`;x)}each c]} ([] a:1 2 3 )
0xeb5cc58551051573c696ea6f746c0dc8
q)md5 `char$-8!{c:cols x;![x;();0b;c!{(#;enlist`;x)}each c]} ([] a:`g#1 2 3 )
0xeb5cc58551051573c696ea6f746c0dc8

Note: If the column contained further nested contents with attributes you would need to extend the above.
If your API enforces chunking you could compare md5 per chunk:
q){c:count x;i:max(1;ceiling c%y);w:y*til i;{[x;y] md5 `char$-8!select from x where i within y}[t] each flip (w;-1+ 1_ w,c)}[20001#t;10000]
0x528380f49e1aa4d5e6b0c4c1ead8924a
0xa02cf08e70a5eb0ad7d094cba44e9146
0x36d6252313d89920d1f50341f8738f8f


The only problem with the solution is that it works on small tables only. When I run it on a larger (~10GB) table md5 \char$ -8! tabI get'limiterror. Is there any way to compute themd5` sum incrementally?

What version of q are you on? (.z.K;.z.k) ? Does md5 (`long$1e+10)#"a" run? (it does for me on 4.1 2024.02.13)

My local version is 4.1 2021.06.12 but the remote version (where the data comes from and I have no control over it) is 3.1 2014.01.24 and is therefore subject to the 2GB serialization limit (https://code.kx.com/q4m3/B_Error_Messages/). md5 (\long$1e+10)#"a"runs fine on both local/remote KDB. So, while your solution is the best in theory, in my practical situation, I am still usingmd5 .Q.s1 tabfor now, although I also wrote a version which applies your method on chunks of data and concatenates the resultingmd5sums to get a sort of aggregatedmd5`.

Added an example of chunking md5

You were close, but the problem is you can't simply use 'string' on a table.  That won't serialize to a string for hashing. You need to serialize the table into a string and then apply the MD5 hash function to the returned data. This way you preserve the binary structure you need for computation.
Steps would be:

Serialize the table

String conversion

Compute the MD5 Hash
Looks like this:
 tab:flip `items`sales`prices!(`nut`bolt`cam`cog;6 8 0 3;10 20 15 20)
 serialTab: -8!tab  // Serialize the table
 md5Hash: md5 serialTab  // Computing the MD5 hash of the serialized table.



So.. The reason for error is as you said, md5 requires a string , (or byte array) but md5 string tab is not going to correctly hash because there is no preservation of the structure you need, (complete binary) for MD5 computation.
I hope this helps you.

To give an alternative to rianoc's answer, another option would be to serialise as JSON e.g.
q)tab:flip `items`sales`prices!(`nut`bolt`cam`cog;6 8 0 3;10 20 15 20)
q)md5 .j.j tab
0xaf7ecdb91b7f7173f7c1026dba460e6d

When serialising as JSON, attributes are not preserved so tables that are identical except for attributes will have same hash e.g.
q)md5 .j.j ([] a:1 2 3 )
0xadc68329679b2bd160a591d5bcc9ab96
q)md5 .j.j ([] a:`g#1 2 3 )
0xadc68329679b2bd160a591d5bcc9ab96

Given that .j.j generates a (JSON) string, I think it may still be susceptible to 'limit errors with very large tables though.

It seems, .j.j is not available in older versions of KDB. Otherwise, it works.

Yes, believe it was added in v3.2; for older versions, you can use json.k https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/e/json.k
